# When should I recalculate starting values for my physics engine's multistep integration?

Tags: integration, physics

I'm writing a physics engine that uses an Adams-Bashforth and Adams-Moulton predictor-corrector pair for integration, and Runge-Kutta 4 to calculate starting values for their initialization.

I am under the impression that I must calculate new starting values upon a radical change to the state of a simulated object - for example, client code directly sets the velocity of an object, rather than applying a force or impulse.

The above is one example; I am wondering in which specific cases recalculation is needed.

It seems to me that direct altering of physical state by external code is an obvious case for recalculating starting values; however, it is less clear to me in the case of, say, an impulse applied to an object as part of collision resolution, or a constant force upon an object suddenly coming into existence.

I store and integrate force and momentum rather than acceleration and velocity, in case that's relevant.

I hope this question is sufficiently descriptive, but if it is not, please ask for details/clarifications. I'll stop here to avoid presenting you with an essay.

Comment: The question might be better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or gamedev.SE.

Comment: You're right, that may have been a better place for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be safe,
I would recalculate
whenever a discontinuity
in either a variable
or any of its derivatives occurs.
Presumably this would not happen
very often,
so it should not affect
updating speed much.